# Distribution of "range" of a process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process, for example a brownian motion (i.e. $X_{t+h} - X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sqrt{h}^2)$).

The difference between now's value $X_t$ and a past value $X_{t-100}$ is

$$M_t = X_{t} - X_{t-100} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sqrt{100}^2)$$

**thus the absolute variation between this past value and now's value, i.e. $|X_{t} - X_{t-100}|$, has a [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).**

## Question:

In a similar fashion, what's the distribution of the **range over a window of width 100** :
$$R_t = \max_{t - 100\leq s \leq t} X_s -  \min_{t - 100\leq s \leq t} X_s$$

**It looks like a log-normal distribution. Can we prove this?**

Moreover, can we prove something when $d\,X_t$ is *something else* than a normal distribution?

---

Numerical evidence: histogram of $M_t$ (folded normal distribution)

[image]

Histogram of $R_t$ :

[image]